# convert python time.time() to java.nanoTime()

Tags: java, python, nanotime

java's System.nanoTime() seems to give a long: 1337203874231141000L
while python time.time() will give something like 1337203880.462787

how can i convert time.time()'s value to something match up to System.nanoTime()?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't.

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()):

> This method can only be used to measure elapsed time and is **not related to any other notion of system or wall-clock time**. The value returned represents nanoseconds since some fixed but arbitrary time (perhaps in the future, so values may be negative).

Answer (score 0):

Divide the output of `System.nanoTime()` by 10^9. This is because it is in nanoseconds, while the output of `time.time()` is in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Python [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html) indicates that the time is epoch based in python.  Java does as [well](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html).  The problem is that python uses a float/double for time, while java uses an int.

I think it would be easier to convert to a standard format, then convert to the target system, rather then try to use the number of seconds since the epoch as you're trying to do.